# Using El inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, el

How to use El tags inside a JavaScript??
I dont want to use class as an identifier in javascript function
i want to use El expression inside Javacript
The Code Below is Working Fine only issue is i m not understanding how to use El in Place of
id in javascript. Please Help me

```
<html>

    <c:forEach items="${studentsList.students}"
        var="student">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $( here i want to use el value as id ).keyup(function(){

    //do something

      });

});
</script> 

</c:forEach>


//Dynamic list of input boxes each having id of particular student

<c:forEach items="${studentsList.students}"
    var="student">
<input type="text" id="{student.id}">

</c:forEach>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<c:out value="${yourVariable}"/>").keyup(function(){

    //do something

});
```